# Where does Linux get information on what to open from?

Tags: shell-script, terminal

For example I have a menu when I right-click. In it, I can see 'open terminal'.

But where does Linux get the information about what to open and how can I change it to a custom option?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please [edit] your question and give us some more context. Where do you see this menu? When you right click on what? In what program? Using what Linux distribution? What desktop environment? This isn't a Linux feature, it will be specific to whatever set of tools you are using.

Comment: You might want to have a look at mime types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Linux" by itself is just a kernel and does not need to know. It is the graphical environment which is usually launching a *runner*, which then again launches the application.

### XDG

Only the *runner* needs to know what to "do". Most graphical environment runners understand and use the [XDG Desktop Entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). A more easy read on the subject would be the [Arch linux wiki page.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_entries) Like most *freedesktop* specifications, you will find that the syntax is very similar to windows' `*.ini` files.

### Quotes

These qoutes are extracted from the arch wiki page, linked above. They hopefully summarize enough to give you the answer you are looking for.

> #### Application entry
>
> Desktop entries for applications, or `.desktop` files, are generally a
>   combination of meta information resources and a shortcut of an
>   application. These files usually reside in `/usr/share/applications` or
>   `/usr/local/share/applications` for applications installed **system-wide**,
>   or `~/.local/share/applications` for **user-specific** applications. User
>   entries take precedence over system entries.

#### Example file contents

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
>
> # The type as listed above
> Type=Application
>
> # The version of the desktop entry specification to which this file complies
> Version=1.0
>
> # The name of the application
> Name=jMemorize
>
> # A comment which can/will be used as a tooltip
> Comment=Flash card based learning tool
>
> # The path to the folder in which the executable is run
> Path=/opt/jmemorise
>
> # The executable of the application, possibly with arguments.
> Exec=jmemorize
>
> # The name of the icon that will be used to display this entry
> Icon=jmemorize
>
> # Describes whether this application needs to be run in a terminal or not
> Terminal=false
>
> # Describes the categories in which this entry should be shown
> Categories=Education;Languages;Java;
> ```

### Run in terminal option

Some runners allow for "Run in terminal" option. In that case, the runner actually executes the default terminal (konsole for KDE, gnome-terminal for gnome) and appends the program's name to the terminal. For example for *konsole* with the `-e` option would run a command instead of the configured shell:

```
konsole -e command
```

Usually the runner will use `.desktop` files for both the terminal and the application to establish their execution commands.